# Make a Mention like SO code started

Tags: javascript, arrays, keypress

```
var userNames = $('.username').map(function(index){
   return $(this).text().replace(/\s/g,'');
});
 userNames = $.unique(userNames).toArray();
  var a = document.getElementById('text_editor_textarea');
  var sc= $(a).data('sceditor');
   var updateText = function() {
     sc ? sc.bind('keypress',sc.updateOriginal).blur(sc.updateOriginal) : setTimeout(updateText,200);
   };
updateText();
 sc.bind('keypress',function(e) {
  if(e.shiftKey && e.which === 64){
       sc.unbind('keypress');
        sc.bind('keyup',function(e) {
           var string = e.which;
       var stringCase = String.fromCharCode(string);
       var word=[];
     if(stringCase !== " " || e.which !== 32) {
         word.push(stringCase);
       } else if(e.which === 8){
         word.pop();
       } else {
        return;
       }
      console.log(word);
        });
     } 
   });
```

What I am trying to do is when the user presses `SHIFT`+`2` creating the @ symbol it then starts adding to an array, multiple problems exist in my code right now. When console.logging the array it does this

```
 ["2"]
 [" "]
 ["M"]
 ["Y"]
 [" "]
 ["W"]
 ["O"]//.etc
```

First off in my code I write `if(stringCase !== " " || e.which !== 32) {` so basically that if it is not a space or blank then to add it (`.push(stringCase)` ) and then I check if the keycode is backspace `8` and if it is pop the array word. Else return it.

For a quick example  http://jsbin.com/erebey/1/edit

Basically I want it to do what it does on SO when typing @USERNAME where the div appears with the usernames name and once you click it it adds that to the textarea.